# Why doesn't it show icons?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

No matter how I try, I always get 404 even though the images are on the server.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(favicon.ico|browserconfig.xml|site.webmanifest|safari-pinned-tab.svg|(android-chrome|favicon|mstile)-[0-9]+x[0-9]+.png|apple-touch-icon(-precompressed.png|-[0-9]+x[0-9]+.png|.png))$ /icons/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What (icon) URL(s) are you requesting? What are you expecting to happen? Where are these files on the filesystem?

Comment: Please give a precise example of such an icon requesting URL.

Comment: @MrWhite @arkascha

The images are in the root of the icons folder. `https://example.com/icons/favicon.ico`
But 404 is returned to me when, for example, I go to this url: `https://example.com/favicon.ico`

Comment: Is this `.htaccess` file in the document root? Do you see an Apache 404 response or is the 404 generated by your script (ie. `index.php`)? The rule you posted should rewrite the request to `/icons/favicon.ico`. If Apache determines that that file does not exist (or is empty) then the request should be rewritten to `index.php`. So there should never be an "Apache 404" if these directives are doing anything. Are other requests like `/foo` being rewritten to `index.php`?

Comment: @MrWhite, Exactly "404 Apache", all other requests go to index.php .

Comment: Try (temporarily) changing the first rule into a "redirect". ie. change `[L]` to `[R,L]`. What happens, do you see an external redirect to `/icons/favicon.ico`?

Comment: @MrWhite, Yes, there is a redirect. It seems to me that this is enough, but I want it to come from the root of the site

Comment: Presumably the icon is successfully served after the redirect (no 404)?

Comment: @MrWhite, Yes, it seems to be a normal redirect, I don’t see any errors. When I navigate to `https://example.com/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png` redirects to `https://example.com/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png`, there is no 404 or 403 error. (if I have console saving enabled, etc.)

Comment: A long shot... try removing the slash prefix on the _substitution string_ (and remove the `R` flag). In other words: `... icons/$1 [L]`.

Comment: @MrWhite, 404 not found